# overload show for list

Tags: haskell, newtype

I want a newline-separated representation instead of the usual comma separated one, for may new data tyepe:

```
newtype SimpleRecord = SimpleRecord ([Char], [Char], Integer)
    deriving (Show)
```

I tried to write this istance of `Show class` :

```
instance  Show [SimpleRecord] where
        show [(SimpleRecord (n, i, c))] = show (SimpleRecord (n, i, c))++['\n']
        show (l:ls) = (show l)++['\n']++(show ls)
```

GHC heavily insults me.

Can someone try to explain me what can I do?

Comment: The class `Show` has a method `showList` so you can customize this. It's how Strings aka `[Char]` get shown differently. Note - you can't derive `Show` for SimpleRecord, you have to do it yourself and define `showList` at the same time.

Comment: You could write a function that's not called `show` and use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the `Show` class is *supposed* to be for producing Haskell source code, which the `Read` class can then read back in. It isn't supposed to be for producing human-readable, "pretty" output.

Having just said that, almost everyone misuses it for the latter, and it can be helpful for debugging purposes.

So, your options are:

1. Write some function not called `show` which does what you want. (As per `AndrewC`'s comment.)
2. Use the `showList` method.

If you write `deriving Show`, this tells the compiler to write all the `Show` methods for you. If you want to write them yourself, you need to take away the `deriving` bit first. Then you can write your instance, which is going to look something like

```
instance Show SimpleRecord where
  show (SimpleRecord (x, y, z)) = ...

  showList rs = unlines (map show rs)
```

---

As an aside, if you didn't already know this, you can write

```
mapM_ print records
```

at the GHCi prompt to print out *any* list of printable things with one element per line.

---

As a final asside, why

```
newtype SimpleRecord = SimpleRecord ([Char], [Char], Integer)
```

rather than

```
data SimpleRecord = SimpleRecord [Char] [Char] Integer
```

Comment: No (again) - `Show` is not supposed to be for _producing Haskell output_. It is for converting Haskell values to Strings. Please read the relevant chapter in the Haskell report. Of course, there are advantages if you have an correspondence between Show and Read instances but there is no obligation for this.

Comment: @stephentetley from the section about derived `Show` instances: "The result of show is a syntactically correct Haskell expression ...". Although there is no obligation that custom `Show` instances behave this way, it *is* intentionally the default. http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18600011.4

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite ambiguos. If I interpret correctly you are trying to change the default `Show` instance for `[SimpleRecord]`.

As GHC has already defined the instance `Show [a]`  when `Show a` is defined. You get following error (after including `FlexibleInstances` extension) when you try to again define instance for `Show [SimpleRecord]`.

```
Matching instances:
      instance Show a => Show [a] -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
      instance Show [SimpleRecord] -- Defined at show.hs:5:11
```

So you need to use `OverlappingInstances` language extension to allow overloading it. 
It states GHC to match the most specific instance.

You might also want to include `FlexibleInstances` extension, which allows to mention arbitrary nested types in instance declaration..

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}
newtype SimpleRecord = SimpleRecord ([Char], [Char], Integer)
    deriving (Show)

instance  Show [SimpleRecord] where
    show [SimpleRecord (n, i, c)] = show (SimpleRecord (n, i, c))++"\n"
    show (l:ls) = show l ++ "\n" ++ show ls
```

You get get more information about these language extensions at [GHC Docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html)

Just a comment on design of your type, It is better to define your type as

```
data SimpleRecord = SimpleRecord String String Integer
```

You get more flexibility here in terms of partial constructor application etc.

Comment: This would be true for most classes.  But `Show` contains a horrible hack for exactly this situation.  You can provide a different implementation of `showList` for your type to customize how lists for your type are handled.

Comment: Is it also worth pointing out that that show instance has a non-exaustive pattern match?

Answer (score 1):

I might have been missing something, but it wasn't clear why you were newtyping (String,String,Integer) rather than what you were concerned to show nicely, namely lists of them.  Then you would evade the universal Show instance for lists:

```
newtype SimpleRecords = SimpleRecords [(String, String, Integer)]

instance Show SimpleRecords where
  show (SimpleRecords []) = ""
  show (SimpleRecords ((n, i, c): xs)) = 
       show (n, i, c) ++ "\n" ++ show (SimpleRecords xs)

 -- Prelude Main> let a = words "We hold these truths to be self-evident"
 -- Prelude Main> let b = words "All the best people are using Clorox"
 -- Prelude Main> let c = zip3 a b [1::Integer ..]
 -- Prelude Main> SimpleRecords c
 -- ("We","All",1)
 -- ("hold","the",2)
 -- ("these","best",3)
 -- ("truths","people",4)
 -- ("to","are",5)
 -- ("be","using",6)
 -- ("self-evident","Clorox",7)
```