# How to print out 2d array haskell

Tags: haskell, 2d, instance, nested-lists, show

I would like to print out 2d array e.g.

```
data a = b [[a]]  
instances Show a where  
show (b array) = "Array:\n" ++ show array   
array = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)],[(5, 6), (7, 8)]]
```

(I hope this pseudocode is readable)
in that way:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]\n
[(5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

the only result I get is:

```
[[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(5, 6), (7, 8)]]
```

I need to use instance Show.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting link on StackOverflow about [the overloading show function for list type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378502/overload-show-for-list).
Code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
module Main where
array = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)],[(5, 6), (7, 8)]]
main = putStrLn $ Main.show array

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Show [[a]] where
show (a:x) = Prelude.show a ++ "\n" ++ Main.show x
show [] = ""
```

Compilation output (unfortunately not warning-free):

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )

main.hs:6:30: warning: [-Wmissing-methods]
    * No explicit implementation for
        either `showsPrec' or `Prelude.show'
    * In the instance declaration for `Show [[a]]'
  |
6 | instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Show [[a]] where
  |                              ^^^^^^^^^^
Linking main ...
```

Output:

```
[(1,2),(3,4)]
[(5,6),(7,8)]
```